# Multiprocess program: ftok vs IPC_PRIVATE

Tags: c, multiprocess

I have some doubts about keys generated by ftok() and by IPC_PRIVATE.

When I call fork(), the key IPC_PRIVATE is automatically shared by both father and sons. Right?

When I call fork(), the key obtained by ftok(...,...) has to be recalculated by every process created. Is it so?

When I call execl(), I can only use the key created by ftok() and not the IPC_PRIVATE one. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ftok does not need to be called by the children.  All ftok does is return an integer based on values from the a file's inode and its second argument.  ftok provides a simple way for unrelated processes to find the same IPC resource.  Here's the implementation from musl-1.1.12 [ftok.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/ipc/ftok.c) (it's easier to read than the glibc version).

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

key_t ftok(const char *path, int id)
{
        struct stat st;
        if (stat(path, &st) < 0) return -1;

        return ((st.st_ino & 0xffff) | ((st.st_dev & 0xff) << 16) | ((id & 0xff) << 24));
}
```

IPC_PRIVATE supplied to msgget(2), semget(2), or shmget(2) means that a new IPC resource should be created.  The resource isn't "private", only newly created.

The Linux man pages say as much in the BUGS section:

> The name choice IPC_PRIVATE was perhaps unfortunate, IPC_NEW would
>   more clearly show its function.

Have a look at the POSIX IPC interfaces: mq_overview(7), sem_overview(7), and shm_overview(7).  To quote the man pages:

> POSIX [...] provides  a  simpler,  and  better designed  interface